# Is it viable to refresh Auth Token on every request?

Tags: security, token, jwt

Does it make sense in a general case for a web API service to send a newly generated token on each request user makes so that client app must use for the next request?

I am thinking of the way to make tokens expiring, but if client app is consuming the data from the API, not require it to sign in again.

I think it's quite easy to implement but not sure if there could be UX or logic/security issues with it.

Comment: Your API is connect to third party API?

Answer (score 7):

This is an existing technique and uses the concept of **sliding sessions** explained by auth0 here: [Refresh Tokens: When to Use Them and How They Interact with JWTs](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/)

Sliding-sessions are sessions that expire after a period of inactivity. **When a user performs an action, a new access token is issued.** If the user uses an expired access token, the session is considered inactive and a new access token is required. This new token can be obtained with a refresh token or requiring credentials

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense for a web API service to send a newly generated token for a new user, so that the client app can use it for subsequent requests on behalf of the user.

Yes, you can make the tokens expire by making them short-lived, given them an early expiry date, so that the user can reauthenticate after a certain period of time that you have specified in the token's expiry date.

When the token is about to expire, you can have an endpoint that renews it. You can also make use of Sliding sessions.

**Sliding-sessions** are sessions that expire after a period of inactivity. As you can imagine, this is easily implemented using access tokens and refresh tokens. When a user performs an action, a new access token is issued. If the user uses an expired access token, the session is considered inactive and a new access token is required. Whether this token can be obtained with a refresh token or a new authentication round, you as the developer has to determine that.

Now, **refresh tokens** are recommended mostly for mobile apps, not web apps. Reason been that refresh tokens are really long-lived, that's how mobile app users are kept logged-in almost forever. You can revoke a refresh token though, in a situation where it has been hijacked or compromised!

You might want to check out this excellent [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) to have more information on how they work!

Oh [@pedrofb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371459/pedrofb) already mentioned that!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to refresh the token on every request. Simply, I would do something like this to  achive the whole process

1. First when the user authenticate with your application, by sending
   their credentials
2. Generate a unique token and send it as back as a response to the
   client
3. Also create a client cookie and set the value with that token, we
   can also specify when the cookie expires, let say it expires every
   24hrs
4. So on subsequent request grab the cookie from your client and
   attached it to your HTTP ajax library (eg. JQuery, RestyGWT,  Apache
   HttpClient or some Android HTTP library) as `Authorization :
   your_cookie_token`
5. Next intercept all request from the server side an check if that
   Header is present `Authorization`
6. Finally  get the Header value, which become your token  so you can
   do some validation on it for security reason's.

You can research more on cookie security and token based authentication/request.

Comment: Without refreshing tokens, you would be vulnerable to attacks where it is enough to steal someone else's token and get full access to this user's data for ever.. This is what your suggestion proposes. Just setting an expiration on a client cookie does nothing.